# Sqlite - User Defined Function With Index

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to use a user defined function in sqlite that uses an index or primary key with blob columns? I have a single column blob primary key of a specific format that represents a range and I want to look for a parameter that is also a blob that might be in one of the ranges. The collation looked promising except it only works with strings. I need something that can return -1, 0 or 1 and take advantage of the index with blobs.

I've tried using a user defined function and it works and finds the correct values in the range, but results in a table scan, since it can only return 0 or 1. Example: `WHERE IN_RANGE(primary_key, search_value) = 1`

I have to stick with this blob format and cannot split into multiple columns for reasons beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have an [index on the result of a deterministic user-defined function](https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html), but that works only if the search value is not one of its parameters, i.e., if you can rewrite it to something like this:

```
... WHERE MyFunc(PrimaryKey) > MyFunc2(SearchValue)  -- or BETWEEN with two values
```

The only way to implement your own comparison is by creating a [virtual table](https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html), and implementing the MATCH operator yourself:

```
... WHERE PrimaryKey MATCH SearchValue
```

Comment: So WHERE MyFunc(PrimaryKey) = MyFunc2(SearchValue) would work? I'm using C# and can store the state of MyFunc to use in MyFunc2.

Comment: If MyFunc reads or writes external state, it is not deterministic. You'd have to encode whatever state you need in its return value.